# Internal EEPROM on PIC16F628A

Tags: pic, eeprom

I'm currently writing code for an alarm system, and I'm having some issues with the EEPROM at the moment of writing/reading (with MPLAB) its contents. I'm not trying to write any variables or configurations yet, but instead I'm trying to wipe it and I constantly fail to write/verify that everything has worked. This is the piece of code that I use to try to wipe the contents of the EEPROM:

```
void default_check(){
    if(PRG){
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            SIREN = !SIREN;
            __delay_ms(170);
        }
        __delay_ms(2640);
    }
    if(PRG){
        SIREN = 1;
        EECON1bits.WREN = 1;
        for (unsigned char i = 0; i <= 127; i++){
            EEDATA = 0x00;
            EEADR = i;
            EECON1bits.WR = 1;
            while (EECON1bits.WR);
        }
        __delay_ms(1000);
        SIREN = 0;
        LEDZ1 = LEDZ2 = LEDZ3 = LEDZ4 = LEDAC = 1;
        __delay_ms(5000);
    }
}
```

`SIREN` is just a macro for a siren, and `PRG` is the reset button. This function is executed after the basic port init but before the peripherals init.

I've extensively read the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/40044G.pdf) of the PIC16F628A and also took a look at the [DS33023 Reference Manual](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/33023a.pdf) looking for any restriction when trying to write zeros to the EEPROM, but found nothing. I was able to write the whole EEPROM with 0xFF only once, with the same code that now doesn't make any changes.

The way I'm reading the contents of the EEPROM is by using the built-in "EE Data Memory" under "Window>Target Memory Views" and also using the "Read EE/flash data memory to file". Right now under "EE Data Memory" I can see all `FF`s from `00` to `7F`, and with the "Read to file" option I get an HEX file that (when opened with notepad) makes no sense at all:

```
:020000040000FA
:10420000FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00B6
:10421000FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00A6
:10422000FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF0096
:10423000FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF0086
:10424000FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF0076
:10425000FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF0066
:10426000FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF0056
:10427000FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF0046
:10428000FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF0036
:10429000FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF0026
:1042A000FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF0016
:1042B000FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF0006
:1042C000FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00F6
:1042D000FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00E6
:1042E000FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00D6
:1042F000FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00FF00C6
:00000001FF
```

I have already tried to "blank" the chip with the MPLAB IPE, but the contents of the EEPROM remain untouched (or maybe rewritten to `FF`). I've also tried to change the `0x00` to a variety of combinations, and nothing got reflected when I tried to read the EEPROM with the IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to follow the EEPROM unlock sequence with EECON2. Write 0x55, write 0xAA, then set WR bit. Disable interrupts (if used) too.

0xFF *is* the 'blank' condition of the EEPROM.

Comment: 10.3 in datasheet.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue. I thought that the procediure was the same as for reading